# Instantsearch.js Algolia + Category pages

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js

I'm looking to implement Algolia's faceting functionality into my Category pages. I have it working great for the search results, but is there anyway to define a set of results when the page loads? e.g Only records which category is 'Shorts' without having to hardlink to a facet/search URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `searchParameters` with an initial filter on the instantsearch instance. There you can add the filter, depending on how your faceting is set up.

[Doc](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/instantsearch.html#struct-InstantSearchOptions-searchParameters)

Comment: Is there more meaty documentation/example of this?